# How to restrict the number of connections to database from particular IP address on Db2 database?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, max-connections

On Db2 v11.5.8.0 Linux x86_64 database every few months some application opens up a lot of connections and it free them up pretty quickly like in 10 mins.

I assume it has to be fat client application from Windows, because for WAS applications number of connections are restricted at application server level.

Checking high water mark I get:

```
db2 get snapshot for dbm | grep "High water mark for agents registered"
```

> High water mark for agents registered          = 4296

What is the best way to limit number of connections by (unknown) IP address? For example I want to restrict maximum number of connection from particular IP address to 100 connections. Bear in mind that I don't know the IP address, it can be any.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this within Db2, but it should be possible to do in your firewall. Something like: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 50000 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 15 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use so called [connect procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=parameters-connect-proc-connect-procedure-name-database) for this.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.CONN_PROC ()
BEGIN
  IF 
    (
    SELECT COUNT (1) 
    FROM TABLE (MON_GET_CONNECTION (NULL, -2)) 
    WHERE CLIENT_IPADDR = SYSIBM.CLIENT_IPADDR
    ) > 100 
  THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75000' 
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Too many connections from the same IP';
  END IF;
END
@

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.CONN_PROC TO PUBLIC@

UPDATE DB CFG USING CONNECT_PROC MYSCHEMA.CONN_PROC@
```

Comment: Clever, did not think of that